# Filter data in highcharts by date and time

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

My web page initially loads the highchart (scatter plot) using the timestamp data for the whole month, but I want to create custom input field that allows to enter date/time range and dynamically plot only those points that are in the range and "hide" everything else. What I already have in mind is that I can add an event listener that listens to change in the input field and reloading the whole chart and filter, but there is a lot of points so I guess this approach is not very efficient. Is there an efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes there is an efficient way, like this: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line. Of course you can also have the controls separate from the chart, just have a look at the demos.

Comment: e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/2q1376Le/2/